# UTF8 para Importar archivo csv con php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

como hago para que me acepte archivs con tildes, eñes u otros simbolos, donde deberia colocarle el utf 8? o de que manera?
Este post lo edite porque resolvi el anterior problema que era que no me insertaba la base de datos pero ahora     logre resolverlo, se que no tengo la necesidad de mostrar todo el codigo pero bueno, es la unica manera que encontre para poder hacer el post de buena manera. Les agradeceria cualquier guia o algun metodo para que me pueda imprimir caracteres raros con simblos o eñes como antes le he mencionado, gracias

```
     $db='database';
     $ru2='../';
     $cl1='numeros';
     $di1='numeros/';
     $di2='numeros/detalle.php';

        function index($rut){
         global $db, $cl1;
       require($rut.DIRMOR.$db.'.php');
       require($rut.DIRMOR.$cl1.'.php');
       $_db = new $db();
       $_cl1 = new $cl1();

      $inf = $_cl1->listar($_db->conect01(),$_db->conect01());

      return $inf;
      }
     function exportar($rut){
     global $db, $cl1;
     require($rut.DIRMOR.$db.'.php');
     require($rut.DIRMOR.$cl1.'.php');
     $_db = new $db();
     $_cl1 = new $cl1();

      $inf = $_cl1->exportar($_db->conect01(),$_db->conect01());

       return $inf;
       }

       if (isset($_REQUEST['importar'])) {
       session_start();
      require('../Const.php');
       include($ru2.DIRMOR.'funct_conc.php');

       if (isset($_POST['importar'])) {
        //conexiones, conexiones everywhere
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $row=1;

        //Aquí es donde seleccionamos nuestro csv
         $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
         echo 'Cargando nombre del archivo: '.$fname.' <br>';
         $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

         if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
         {
            //si es correcto, entonces damos permisos de lectura para subir
            $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
            $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
            {

                $campo0 = $data[0];
                $campo1 = $data[1];
                $campo2 = $data[2];
                $campo3 = $data[3];
                $campo4= $data[4];
                $campo5= $data[5];
                $campo6= $data[6];
                $campo7= $data[7];
                $campo8= $data[8];
                $campo9= $data[9];
                $campo10= $data[10];
                $campo11= $data[11];
                $campo12 = $data[12];
                $campo13 = $data[13];
                $campo14 = $data[14];
                $campo15= $data[15];
                $campo16= $data[16];
                $campo17= $data[17];
                $campo18= $data[18];
                $campo19= $data[19];
                $campo20= $data[20];
                $campo21= $data[21];
                $campo22= $data[22];
                $campo23 = $data[23];
                $campo24 = $data[24];
                $campo25 = $data[25];
                $campo26= $data[26];
                $campo27= $data[27];
                $campo28= $data[28];
                $campo29= $data[29];
                $campo30= $data[30];
                $campo31= $data[31];
                $campo32= $data[32];
                $campo33= $data[33];
                $campo34= $data[34];
                $campo35= $data[35];
                $campo36= $data[36];
                $campo37= $data[37];
                $campo38= $data[38];
                $campo39= $data[39];
                $campo40= $data[40];
                $campo41= $data[41];
                $campo42= $data[42];
                $campo43= $data[43];
                $campo44= $data[44];
                $campo45= $data[45];
                $campo46= $data[46];
                $campo47= $data[47];
                $campo48= $data[48];
                $campo49= $data[49];
                $campo50= $data[50];
                $campo51= $data[51];
                $campo52= $data[52];
                $campo53= $data[53];
                $campo54= $data[54];
                $campo55= $data[55];
                $campo56= $data[56];

              $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$cl1." 
               (nrocliente,
                nrowo,
                wotype,
                razoncreacion,
                servicecreacion,
                subtype,
                clasificacion,
                ird_modem,
                codinstalador,
                nombreinstalador,
                codinstaladorpadre,
                nombreinstaladorpadre,
               coddealer,
                nombredealer,
                codigodealerpadre,
                dealerpadre,
            estadowo,
              fechacreacionwo,
              fechacumplimiento,
              fechaultimoagendamiento,
          fechaultimaasignacion,
               textbox16,
              atraso_ct_wo,
                atraso_ct_sp,
                   acciontomada,
            fecha_1_pasaje_terminada,
           estadocliente,
           tipocliente,
           apellidonombre,
            direccionins,
            extrains,
               x,
               y,
               t,
           cpins,
            localidadins,
              provinciains,
             telefonoparticularins,
            telefonolaboralins,
             faxinstalacion,
                 fax2instalacion,
              email_instdireccionfac,
                  extrafac,cpfac,
             localidadfact,
            provinciafac,
               telefonoparticularfac,
                  telefonolaboralfac,
               faxfac,
          fax2fac,
       email_fact,
             zona,
               observacion,modelo,nroserie,nrosc) VALUES ('".$campo0."','".$campo1."',
              '".$campo2."', '".$campo3."', '".$campo4."', '".$campo5."', '".$campo6."',
              '".$campo7."', '".$campo8."', '".$campo9."', '".$campo10."', '".$campo11."',
              '".$campo12."', '".$campo13."', '".$campo14."', '".$campo15."',
              '".$campo16."', '".$campo17."', '".$campo18."', '".$campo19."',
              '".$campo20."', '".$campo21."', '".$campo22."', '".$campo23."',
              '".$campo24."', '".$campo25."', '".$campo26."', '".$campo27."',
              '".$campo28."', '".$campo29."', '".$campo30."', '".$campo31."',
               '".$campo32."', '".$campo33."', '".$campo34."', '".$campo35."',
               '".$campo36."', '".$campo37."', '".$campo38."', '".$campo39."',
               '".$campo40."', '".$campo41."', '".$campo42."', '".$campo43."',
                '".$campo44."', '".$campo45."', '".$campo46."', '".$campo47."',
                 '".$campo48."', '".$campo49."', '".$campo50."', '".$campo51."',
                 '".$campo52."', '".$campo53."', '".$campo54."', '".$campo55."', 
                  '".$campo56."') ;";
                mysqli_query(conect01(),$sql);
                $row++;
            }
            //cerramos la lectura del archivo "abrir archivo" con un "cerrar archivo"
            fclose($handle);
            $_SESSION['stat'] = "import";
            header("Location: ".URL.$di1);
            exit();
         }
         else
         {
            //si aparece esto es posible que el archivo no tenga el formato adecuado, inclusive 
      cuando es cvs, revisarlo para             
            //ver si esta separado por " ; "
            $_SESSION['stat'] = "noimport";
            header("Location: ".URL.$di1);
            exit();
              }
          }
         exit();
       }

          ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

la base de datos tiene que aceptarte los caracteres especiales, te recomiendo cambiar a utf8_general_ci y en la conexión en php podes hacer lo siguiente, luego de conectar poniendo tu host, user, password y db, pasarle un query donde también hagas un set del utf seria algo asi:

```
$conexion->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

de esta forma ya no te debería dar problemas al insertar datos con caracteres especiales en la db.